# Class extends SKScene but cannot access its attributes

Tags: swift, inheritance, sprite-kit

I have a Menu class that extends SKScene, but I cannot access view, which is an attribute of SKScene. Instead I get the following error: "Instance member 'view' cannot be used on type Menu."

Is there anything special I need to do to access this? It seems like it should already be able to call that.

Here is a shortened version of the class:

```
class Menu: SKScene {
var blueButton: Button!
var touchNode: SKSpriteNode!
var newScene: SKScene?

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    blueButton = self.childNode(withName: "Start") as! Button

} 
...
class func transitionToScene(node: String) {
    var scene = SKScene()

    switch node {
        case "NewGame":
            scene = GameScene()

        default:
            debugPrint("transition to scene called on no button")
    }
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
    //(self.view as! SKView).presentScene(scene)

    self.view.presentScene(scene)
}
```

The issue comes at the last line. Above it I commented out a different attempt, but this also did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to note a difference between instance methods and type methods. Instance methods are called on an instance of a particular type. You define them like this:

```
class SomeClass {

    func myInstanceMethod() {

    }
}
```

Type methods, are methods that are called on a type itself. You define them by using `static` keyword, or as in your example `class` keyword (class keyword  allows subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation of that method).

So, in short you should use an instance method, because self refers in your case to the current  instance, not to the Menu type (just remove the class keyword).

Comment: this is probably a super stupid question, but what's the difference between a `static func` and a `class func`?

Comment: @Confused  If a method is declared as class func, then subclasses can override this method. Methods defined as static cannot be overridden in subclasses.